# Insert comment into Swift Combine pipeline

Tags: swift, debugging, operators, combine

Here is a snippet from my Publisher:

```
let cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map(\.data)
    .decode([Object].self, decoder: JSONDecoder()
    .sink(...)
```

If I want to know what's happening when, I could do this:

```
let cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map(\.data)
    .map { print("Before decoding"); return $0 }
    .decode([Object].self, decoder: JSONDecoder()
    .map { print("After decoding"); return $0 }
    .sink(...)
```

Is there a better way than this (ab)use of `map` or similar?

Comment: `.print("Before Coding")`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sorry, that prints a message for every status change of the whole publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the obvious answer is the `.print()` operator. If you only want to see print statements for a particular kind of event, then use `handleEvents` instead.

```
let cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map(\.data)
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in print("before decoding") })
    .decode(type: [Object].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in print("after decoding") })
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { _ in })
```

Comment: It's working well, thank you. This is what `handleEvents` is intended for.